# what is giving margin between the elements in this form

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome-devtools

please see the example
http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#inline-forms

I fail to see what is causing the gap between the `form-group` and the button, and also between the `form-group`s. When I use bootstrap 4 with `flexbox` enabled, all my elements (inputs and button) collapses without any margin between them.

How can see what is causing the `form-group` highlighted and the button next to it? I could not find it through chrome inspector.

thanks.

[image]

Comment: We need more than an image to help, and I'm pretty sure you know how to ask a proper question :), so please post a minimal working code snippet that reproduces the issue

Comment: sorry for wrong wordings. my question was in the above link (bs4 doc), what is causing the space and how can I see it through chrome inspector.

Comment: Sorry my answer thought you were asking about the white space between the name input box and the email label, but the answer is the same when talking about the space between the email text box and the button.  Remove the whitespace from the html and the button will be next to the email textbox.

Comment: Also you should note, that the example on that bootstrap page is using border-box, and the elements aren't set to display:flex;  So if you are using a flexbox layout, I think it's expected to smush together like you are seeing in your code. However, I'm definitely not an expert on flexbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of a tricky thing, but it has to do with the fact that the two DIVS are set as `display:inline-block` which means they are part of an inline formatting context, and each div almost behaves as if it's a word in a sentence. We want spaces between words to render, so the html is very subtly hinting that the space in the html should be rendered as a space.  In chrome inspector, the way it formats the elements tree hides this from you, but if you edit the html on the parent element within chrome inspector and remove the space you can recreate what you are seeing in my codepen example.

Here is a code pen, to demonstrate: http://codepen.io/MarkAtRamp51/pen/XKYNpZ

Notice the difference between the two:

Excerpt from HTML that displays whitespaces between the two form groups

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2"
placeholder="Jane Doe">   </div>   
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Email</label>
```

and

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe">
  </div><div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Email</label>
```

Notice in the second example the two DIV's are butted up next to each other.

You can find more information about this here:
https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ and 
https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html

Comment: You can remove the space between the button and the text box using .btn{
  margin:-4px;
} in the CSS in the code pen example.

Comment: You can also do that to remove the space between the name text box and the email label.

Comment: Yes .form-control{
  margin:-4px;
} would remove all of the space

Comment: I misread his question, what i'm stating in my answer also applies to the whitespace between the button and the email textbox. Removing the whitespace in the html will remove the rendered space.

Comment: Right, but I was answering the question of "Where does the whitespace come from, and how do i see it in chrome inspector?"

Comment: thanks Mark. your answer was right on and thanks for the links. I render my form with reactjs, and will explore whether I can set space between elements. thanks again.

Comment: Oh man. I lost 3 hours on exactly this example from Twitter Bootstrap. Then I used your example Mark and lost another 30 minutes to learn that JSX removes whitespaces.